# How to convert factory boy instance as json

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, factory-boy

I have a model that relates to some others and I want to make an instance of model factory with `factory boy` package and send it as `json` to rest API in django rest framework.

UserFactory:

```
class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User
    first_name = factory.Faker('name')
    username = factory.Faker('word')
    language = factory.SubFactory(LanguageFactory)
```

LanguageFactory:

```
class LanguageFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
class Meta:
    model = Language

name = factory.Faker('language_name')
```

When I use:

```
factory.build(dict, FACTORY_CLASS=UserFactory)
```

it returns:

```
{'first_name': "Agent 001", 'username': 'john_doe', 'language': <Language: Catalan>}
```

where language is another model factory but I need it as json to post or patch test.

How would I get something like this?

```
{'first_name': "Agent 001", 'username': 'john_doe', 'language': [{'name': 'English'}, {'name': 'French'}]}
```

Comment: show UserFactory code

Comment: I've Edited this post and add factories.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues/68#issuecomment-636452903

Comment: I've test this before and it returns: `functools.partial(<function generate_dict_factory.<locals>.dict_factory at 0x7ffa655afaf0>, <class 'apps.common.factories.MovieFactory'>)`

Comment: UserDictFactory = generate_dict_factory(UserFactory)---> call it: UserDictFactory()

Comment: Thank you. It works for me as you mentioned. call the `UserDictFactory()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in comment mentioned the factory boy doesn't have inner dict factory by itself.
The answer in [github](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/issues/68#issuecomment-636452903) worked.

First you should make a function that gets factory class and dict all classes in it:

```
from functools import partial
from typing import Any, Dict

from factory import Factory
from factory.base import StubObject


def generate_dict_factory(factory: Factory):
    def convert_dict_from_stub(stub: StubObject) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        stub_dict = stub.__dict__
        for key, value in stub_dict.items():
            if isinstance(value, StubObject):
                stub_dict[key] = convert_dict_from_stub(value)
        return stub_dict

    def dict_factory(factory, **kwargs):
        stub = factory.stub(**kwargs)
        stub_dict = convert_dict_from_stub(stub)
        return stub_dict

    return partial(dict_factory, factory)
```

then for usage:

```
# example of usage
UserDictFactory = generate_dict_factory(UserFactory)
```

and finally if call `UserDictFactory()` returns what we need.

Answer (score 1):

I was using the answer from Mahmood, and I realized that it was not working properly for lists (when `foos = factory.List(FooFactory)`). In this case we would expect to get back a list, but with the original code we get back a dict where the keys are the list indexes as strings.

I made the following modification to fix it:

```py
def generate_dict_factory(factory: factory.Factory):
    def stub_is_list(stub: StubObject) -> bool:
        try:
            return all(k.isdigit() for k in stub.__dict__.keys())
        except AttributeError:
            return False

    def convert_dict_from_stub(stub: StubObject) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        stub_dict = stub.__dict__
        for key, value in stub_dict.items():
            if isinstance(value, StubObject):
                stub_dict[key] = (
                    [convert_dict_from_stub(v) for v in value.__dict__.values()]
                    if stub_is_list(value)
                    else convert_dict_from_stub(value)
                )
        return stub_dict

    def dict_factory(factory, **kwargs):
        stub = factory.stub(**kwargs)
        stub_dict = convert_dict_from_stub(stub)
        return stub_dict

    return partial(dict_factory, factory)
```